# Vue2: update other form inputs from programmatic v-model change?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I programmatically change the v-model. How can one update the other inputs attached? Is it marking it somehow two-way, or forcing a render?

html:

```
<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <div v-for='item in items'>
      <input type='checkbox' v-on:change='check(item,$event)' v-model='item.checked'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var app=new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
        {'checked': true},
      {'checked': true}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    check: function(item, event) {
        var newlyChecked = event.srcElement.checked;

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].checked = newlyChecked;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/w5c6b7kt/1/

Goal (for this sample) is to have all other checkboxes check or uncheck when one is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console while debugging your checkboxes you can see that there is an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined

This is because you have to reference the Vue object via `this` in order to access and change its properties while you are in a method of that object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
  this.items[i].checked = newlyChecked;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w5c6b7kt/2/

Comment: thanks - I had another items array in my larger sample that was conflicting - thanks again - works.